# combine column name with level of factors in data frame

Tags: r

I have this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c('a', 'b', 'c'), B = c('d', 'e', 'c'))
```

and would like to transform it to this:

```
    A   B
1 A:a B:d
2 A:b B:e
3 A:c B:c
```

My current not working miserable 'loop' attempt (using apply version preferred) is this:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    for (col in 1:ncol(df1)) {
        levels(colnames(df1)[col])[levels(colnames(df1)[col]) == df1[row, col]] <- paste0(colnames(df1)[col], ":", df1[row, col])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way with `mapply`:

```
data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) paste0(y, ':', x), df1, c('A', 'B')))
#    A   B
#1 A:a B:d
#2 A:b B:e
#3 A:c B:c
```

Or you could do:

```
data.frame(A = paste0('A:', df1$A),
           B = paste0('B:', df1$B))
```

But I would go for the first option if you have multiple columns that you would like to use this logic on.

Comment: to make it more robust , instead of  hard coding value to `c('A', 'B')`, do `names(df1)` ?

Comment: You could squish this logic up a bit too since `Map/mapply` loops over all arguments - `df1[] <- Map(paste, names(df1), df1, sep=":")` or `data.frame(Map(paste, names(df1), df1, sep=":")` if you don't want to overwrite.

Comment: Very true for both. I just thought the OP might not have the same names between column names and the ones needed, in his original data, so I gave a more generic answer without using them.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question, how can the transformation process be suppressed (i.e. not every transformation is shown in the console).

Comment: In what sense do you mean? On the console only the final data frame is printed. What would you like not to be printed?

Comment: Ignore me - I have to assign to df

Answer (score 3):

An option using `lapply` where we go through each column and `paste` the name of the column along with column values.

```
df1[] <- lapply(seq_along(df1), function(x) paste0(names(df1)[x],":", df1[,x]))

df1
#    A   B
#1 A:a B:d
#2 A:b B:e
#3 A:c B:c
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you want to do it using `tidyverse`:

```
df1 %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>% #Creating row IDs
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>% #Transforming the data from wide to long
 mutate(temp = paste(var, val, sep = ":")) %>% #Combining the column names with the level of factors
 select(-val) %>%
 spread(var, temp) %>% #Transforming the data back to wide format
 select(-rowid) #Deleting the redundant variable

    A   B
1 A:a B:d
2 A:b B:e
3 A:c B:c
```